# Hiding some request parameters/query parameters and response schema fields in swagger in loopback

Tags: swagger, openapi, loopback

We have a requirement in which we have to hide some request parameters/query parameters and response schema fields in swagger. We tried some options but they are not working as expected. As per the documentation we can’t implement this in loopback. Does anyone have any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

In LoopBack 4, you can implement a custom OpenAPI Spec Enhancer that will redact (hide) request parameters and schema fields from the API spec produced by the server - see https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Extending-OpenAPI-specification.html

We don't provide such functionality in LoopBack 3. If you are accessing the generated Swagger spec via API Explorer, then  you can fork [`loopback-component-explorer`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-explorer) module and add the code to customize the generated schema - see the function `mountSwagger` in [index.js](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-explorer/blob/7bcdfa7350c881cb65b3eaa5650d0fbe665af4cf/index.js#L120)